# After upgrade to iOS11, Photo uploads files to icloud even though the phone is on mobile network

Tags: icloud, photos, ios, iphone

Before iOS11, the photo app does not upload newly snapped photo to icloud if the phone is still on a mobile app. It will usually say, to the effect, "Upload paused while on mobile network" at the bottom of the 'Photos' section.

However since I upgraded to iOS 11, the photo will upload  regardless the type of network connection. It killed my mobile data! On one weekend, 1 Gb of data was sucked away because of the upload.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, is there a solution?

This is the 'Mobile Data' settings of photo app:

[image: 'Mobile Data' settings of photo app]

Comment: Did you check the upload settings in Settings->Photos?

Comment: I did not change any setting of photo since the upgrade. It uses Mobile Data but the 'Unlimited Updates' is off. The mobile data is needed to be on if I want to pull old photos from iCloud when I open them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ios11 **feature**. (I think it is actually a **bug** because I did not observe this kind of behaviour before)

I find that I put the phone in 'Low Power' mode, the Photo will not attempt to upload the photo automatically.

[image]

Now I will turn it on before I take any photo while on mobile network.

Answer (score -1):

One suggestion would be to set Photos to keep full copies of your photos on your iPhone if you have enough space.
Photos and Music are reasons it is better to buy a larger storage iPhone even with iCloud.
When you are on WiFi you just download a full copy of everything.